# Kubernetes: Run Pods only on EC2 Nodes that have GPUs

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, monitoring

I am setting up GPU monitoring on a cluster using a `DaemonSet` and NVIDIA DCGM. Obviously it only makes sense to monitor nodes that have a GPU.

I'm trying to use `nodeSelector` for this purpose, but [the documentation states that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector):

> For the pod to be eligible to run on a node, **the node must have each of the indicated key-value pairs as labels** (it can have additional labels as well). The most common usage is one key-value pair.

I intended to check if the label `beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type` was any of those:

```
[p3.2xlarge, p3.8xlarge, p3.16xlarge, p2.xlarge, p2.8xlarge, p2.16xlarge, g3.4xlarge, g3.8xlarge, g3.16xlarge]
```

But I don't see how to make an `or` relationship when using `nodeSelector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) was the solution:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dcgm-exporter
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        description: |
          This `DaemonSet` provides GPU metrics in Prometheus format.
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type
                operator: In
                values:
                - p2.xlarge
                - p2.8xlarge
                - p2.16xlarge
                - p3.2xlarge
                - p3.8xlarge
                - p3.16xlarge
                - g3.4xlarge
                - g3.8xlarge
                - g3.16xlarge
```